# A positive integer $k$ such that the last $2015$ digits of $53^k$ are all $3$

Tags: number-theory

> Show that there is a positive integer $k$ such that the last $2015$ digits of $53^k$ are all $3$.

We need $3 \cdot 53^k \equiv -1 \pmod{10^{2015}}$. I didn't see a way to prove there exists such an integer $k$ because the modulus is so large. How do we prove there exists such an integer $k$?

Comment: @MatthewConroy That's an evergreen comment on MSE. Looking the reputation of OP, I guess (s)he also knows that.

Comment: Why not try showing that this with 2015 replaced by 2, 3, 4, etc., and see what patterns develop?

Comment: @JaideepKhare Continually fresh or self-renewing?

Comment: @MatthewConroy What? I couldn't get it.

Comment: @JaideepKhare I do not know what you mean by "evergreen comment".

Comment: @MatthewConroy I mean, most people on this website (including me) leave *this* comment on questions by new users, or whichever question is lacking attempt. Evergreen, because I see this comment at least once everyday .

Answer (score 3):

Once we find a power of $53$ whose last four digits are $3$, we can get the desired $k$. Specifically, let $a$, $k_4$ be integers such that $53^{k_4}\equiv a\mod 10^4$. I claim that for every integer $n\geq 4$, there is a positive integer $k_n$ such that $$53^{k_n}\equiv a\mod 10^n.$$
The proof is induction on $n$. The base case $k_4$ exists by hypothesis. Now, let $n\geq 4$ and suppose $53^{k_{n}}\equiv a\mod 10^n$. We will have $53^{k_n}= a+10^nb$ for some integer $b$. We can compute directly that $53^{500}\equiv 1+10^4\mod 10^5$. It follows that 
$$
53^{500\cdot 10^{n-4}b a^{-1}}\equiv 1+10^n ba^{-1}\mod 10^{n+1},
$$
where $a^{-1}$ denotes any inverse of $a$ modulo $10$. We take $k_{n+1}=k_n-500\cdot 10^{n-4}ba^{-1}$ to get
$$
53^{k_{n+1}}\equiv (a+10^nb)(1-10^n ba^{-1})\equiv a\mod 10^{n+1}.
$$

To finish the problem, check that
$$
53^{29}\equiv 3333\mod 10^4.
$$

Comment: Can you further elaborate the answer to explicitly find $k_{2015}$?

Comment: Using this recursive construction, one can find $k_{2015}$ explicitly with a computer. It has $2015$ digits, though, so maybe I won't put it in the answer.

Comment: Can you explain how $53^{500 \cdot 10^{n-4}ba^{-1}} \equiv 1+10^n ba^{-1} \pmod{10^{n+1}}$?